# How do I add custom headers to a urllib request?

Tags: python, urllib

I've looked up the documentation on the urllib module, however, I couldn't quite understand how to add headers to a request as I'm trying to download a file.

I'm used to using the requests module, however, that isn't a working solution for me as it is simply not downloading anything.

```
Headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

index_name = 'Index.m3u8'
Videoindex = 'http://test.com/notreal.ts'

indexresponse = urllib.request.urlopen(Videoindex, headers=Headers)
with open(index_name,'wb') as x:
    x.write(indexresponse.read())

audio_name = 'Audio.m3u8'
Audioindex = 'http://test.com/notreal.aac'

audioresponse = urllib.request.urlopen(Audioindex, headers=Headers)
with open(audio_name,'wb') as y:
    y.write(audioresponse.read())
```

I understand that you can't parse the header argument inside urlopen, but is there any sort of way I can add this? I'd rather not implement the headers line by line as there are quite a few.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You really should use `requests` for this type of work.  It makes life easier.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Comment: Hi, I've tried using requests, however, when no requests are actually going through.

Answer (score 0):

I second the requests library approach. It allows for rest api functionality. You can also specify parameters for querying.

```py
Videoindex = 'http://test.com/notreal.ts'
Headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

r = requests.get(url=VideoIndex, headers=Headers)
```